# NULL not initializing

Tags: c, fopen

i'm new to C programming but am getting the hang of it. I'm working on a FILE function and the function will never return NULL. This happens even when the file does not exist and is initialized as "r". The code has worked before, but after that it has kept returning TRUE. I have written the code multiple ways but all return as the file being there. I have even changed the file name to make a completely different file but still get same results. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Thanks everyone. I've gotten it to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("c:\\lest.txt", "w");
    if(fp == NULL)
        {
        printf("File Not Available\n");
        exit(0);
        }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to be checking fp against null, not fopen.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("c:\\lest.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL)
        {
        printf("File Not Available\n");
        exit(0);
        }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Technical_Customs: Are you aware you edited an answer instead of your question? fopen() works fine. But there seems to be a bit of confusion here.

Comment: Yea sorry. I noticed when I did it. I'm use to viewing this site through my phone.

Answer (score 4):

```
 fp = fopen("c:\\lest.txt", "r");
 if(fopen == NULL)
```

These lines are so wrong. `fopen()` is a standard  function. So the `fopen` (without parenthesis) **will always be non-NULL** as it represents the function pointer of `fopen()`.

What you should do is to check the return value of `fopen()`. Which is in this case `fp`.

```
if(fp==NULL){
    perror("fopen");
    exit(1);
}
```

Also note,

1. To print exact error you should use `perror()` function.
2. `exit(0)` will return 0 to OS. Which indicates success. Better use `exit(1)`.

Comment: @Technical_Customs: No, it isn't.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of testing `fopen` for null, change the conditional to test `fp` for `NULL` instead:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE fp*;

    fp = fopen("c:\\lest.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("File Not Available\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as u are saying that even if change the file name & then call **fp = fopen("c:\lest.txt", "w");** even there is no existing file of name **lest.txt**, u get **fp!=NULL**.

it happens because if the specified file is not present then new file with the specified name in the fopen() function is created then it's file pointer is returned so i think u have gotten ur answer.

for more info please see the man page of the function fopen() http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen